# No items found when adding new tables to existing report

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle10g, odbc, windows-7-x64

I made a new report using Crystal Reports XI Release 2 Service Pack 6 on a 64 bit Windows 7. I want to connect to an Oracle 10G database through ODBC drivers.  I can run pre-existing reports with no problem, and I can even add columns from tables used in a pre-existing report. But I cannot add new tables to a pre-existing report.

I'll select Report Wizard or Blank Report, and I'll select Favorites, History, New Connections or Current Connections. I can select Service with no problem, but when I go down to the next level I click on my schema and get:

> No items found.

I have tried increasing my NTTablesMax in my computer's registry from 8,000 to 50,000 and then to 100,000, but none of those solved the issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: much better if you insert some image here in no items found

Comment: Sorry, the image I did a copy and paste on will not paste.  The image just says "no items found" in a blue rectangular box with white letters.